# iPhone distribution Over the Air

Tags: iphone, distribution, adhoc

In order to distribute my iPhone for test purposes on a couple of device Over the Air, I have created an AdHic distribution profile and followed the explanation I found in this blog (sorry it's in French but the screenshot are quite detailled):

http://www.media-business.biz/content/iphone-cr%C3%A9ez-votre-propre-appstore

I install the position profile on the device from my web site but when it comes to the application I have an error message saying it's impossible to download the app.
Is this a known problem ?
Thanks a lot for your help.
Regards,
Luc

ps: just adding a last minute question... is there a place I could see some error logs ?? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found [testflightapp.com](https://testflightapp.com), that is really great !

Answer (score 5):

Here's [another explanation in English](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/).  This distribution method only works with devices running iOS 4.x

Comment: Hello, sorry the link you provide is not valid. My iPhone is running iOS 4.

Comment: Thanks. Well, this is what I've done. I cannot really understand where I missed something. I created a distribution AdHoc provisionning profile with the 3 UUIDs I need to deploy the app on. It seems to be created correctly.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

- The IPA file name matches exactly the name of the server (case sensitive).
- The bundle version number is identical in the IPA file and your plist file, and that you update it every time you make a new IPA (or the phone will think it's already installed and not update)
- You are using an itms-services:// link to point to the plist file, and the plist file has the correct URL to your IPA file.
- When you go into Organizer and press the "Share" button, you select exactly the distribution profile you intend to use (sometimes I think it can select the wrong one with automatic).

Comment: hmmm... I am not really sure with item 2 and 3. Where can I see the bundle version ? Also, what is the itms-services ? Thank you for you help. Luc

Comment: bundle version is in the info.plist, and also in the plist that "Share for Enterprise" gives you.  itms-services is the form of link you have to use on your web site that the person browsing with the phone is supposed to click, so instead of http:// you use itms-services:// (there's an example URL also in the generated plist file).

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue, and it was because I hadn't installed an AdHoc mobileprovision file and was building against my Dev mobileprovision. Check that first.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Well, I am not surprised this could be a problem link to the profile :( How did you manage to have it working then ? Where do I select the Dev mobile provision instead of the AdHoc one ?

Comment: Select your Target, click build, under Configuration select Release, then for Code Signing, choose your AdHoc mobileprovision file, rather than your Developer mobileprovision. Then when you build your app, select Release, and then Build And Archive. This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also think testflightapp.com is the most convinient way to do this, as long as the beta testers you'll contact accept to sign up there. The great additional value is that if you install their SDK in your app, you'll be able to monitor the activity of your beta-testers (for instance you can define waypoints with definite names).

However, if:

- You already konw the UDIDs of your beta testers
- You just want them to be able to click on a link from your server to start installing the app,

  - You don't need "in app" follow-up and just request feedback from your testers,

Then I strongly recommend [this](http://blog.touchon.asia/2012/03/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota) tutorial: