# How to Provision a Device When it's Not Connected to Computer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

this is driving me absolutely crazy. I'm trying to deploy an application to one of our developers who just bought a new iPhone, but the problem is that he's nowhere near the office right now so I can't physically connect his device. Any ideas how I can add a provisioning profile to his device manually without him having to travel so far? I've already sent him the profile, and added his UDID to the devices section of the provisioning portal... now I just can't figure out how to add the provisioning profile to his device over the air. Any ideas?

Thank you!

EDIT: already using test flight, but this developers device is under the heading "These teammate's devices were not identified in the embedded.mobileprovision for this build."

Comment: Are you trying to build the app on his phone or have him build the app?

Comment: the app has already been built, im trying to install it on his phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASSUMPTION:  Purpose is for testing.  If this is a Production distribution in an Enterprise Developer license, I don't have the answer for you.

What I did was, first create an Ad Hoc Distribution Profile containing those devices.

Second, archive your app in XCode.

Third, go to the Archives window (CMD-Shift-2), then pick Archives.  Click Share to create an IPA file.  MAKE SURE TO SELECT THE CORRECT PROVISIONING PROFILE TO SIGN THE APP WITH AT THIS POINT.

Then, e-mail the IPA file to the person.

This person will then be able to synch the app via iTunes (in iTunes, pick File / Add to Library, browse and pick the file.)

However, when the provisioning profile expires, the app will no longer launch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com/)

You have to create an account. He has to register with his device with your account (you can send a link, instructions in testflight), this will add a testflight profile to his device. With this you have his UUID and all this stuff. Now sign and export your application following the [testflight tutorial](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4) and upload it to testflight app. All this done, the client can install your app without needing itunes or a computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already entered the device's UDID in your portal and have mobileprovisions including it, try [Over the Air Provisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240259/iphone-distribution-over-the-air) from your web site.

If you don't have a web server under your control, TestFlight offers one as a service. (But I have no affiliation and haven't tried it yet.)

Answer (score -1):

http://developer.apple.com

he needs to be logged in.
then go to the provisioning portal, and request a certificate. you need to approve it. then he adds this certificate to Xcode organizer and he can user the device